# Contenteditable move cursor to end on paste using medium.js?

Tags: javascript

Source: http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/

**Goal: When we paste content in editor allow only `<p>, <b>, <a>, and <i>` tags only**

Steps:

1. copy some big paragraph with title in web pages.
   [image]
2. Paste in medium.js rich text box.
   [image]

3.Cursor will not move at end after paste. We have to move at the end of pasted text.

[image]

Please Help this issue Thanks
Or i appreciate if you share me any other plugin like medium.js.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have found is an issue with Medium.js.  I went ahead and created the issue in the project (here - https://github.com/jakiestfu/Medium.js/issues/103) and plan on solving this soon.  Thanks again for the interest and the feedback!

Comment: Thanks [**Robert Plummer**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1324039/robert-plummer). I really appreciate your work. Waiting for your answer!...

Comment: I believe this has been solved in v1 and master.  Please try again, we look forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I have a some experience with contenteditable and found this bug while developing my own editor and while working with CKeditor. It sometimes happens not only after pasting text, it also happens after modifying DOM tree. Well, actually, maybe I do not understand the problem completely, but it looks very close. And, unfortunately, I did not find a solution to this problem, and I think it can be browsers bug. I hope, I'm wrong.

Comment: Im sure it is not browser issue. you can try this function in online google editable word document and microsoft word document. it work great..

Answer (score 0):

I did not use medium.js but I had a similar issue with a custom contenteditable that after paste it didn't move to the end of the paste.

In the end I ended up with this combo which does what I need it to do.

This is what I went up doing:

```
/** Paste the text **/
range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementText));

/** set the collapse to false, this will keep all text selected, updating the range object itself **/
range.collapse(false);
/** use the values of the updated range object to reset it start position **/
range.setStart(range.endContainer,range.endOffset);
/** collapse it to turn it into a single cursor **/
range.collapse(true);
/** remove everything **/
sel.removeAllRanges();
/** add our fresh range **/
sel.addRange(range);
```